# Oracle rman archive aren't deleted

Tags: oracle, archive, rman

I created a physical standby to our primary. I used duplicate from backup to preform this duplicate. The duplication process took rman 12 hours. After the duplicate finished I configured the broker. Then I realized that I have a transfer lag because during those 12 hours I have backed up all the archives in my primary with the next script :

```
run
{
ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH1 TYPE 'SBT_TAPE';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH2 TYPE 'SBT_TAPE';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH3 TYPE 'SBT_TAPE';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH4 TYPE 'SBT_TAPE';
BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL DELETE INPUT;
RELEASE CHANNEL CH1;
RELEASE CHANNEL CH2;
RELEASE CHANNEL CH3;
RELEASE CHANNEL CH4;
}
```

Therefore, I restored the needed archives and I also configured :
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO applied on standby.

I had some problems with my dr so I stopped the transport and the apply in the dgmgrl prompt. After that I configured:

```
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE;
```

Now, when I run the archives backup script (every 4 hours) it doesn't delete the archives that it backed up. As a result of that every 4 hours I backup archives that were already backed up. Can someone explain to me what went wrong ?

Comment: everything looks ok - try to delete/disable your configuration using dgmgrl

Comment: Hi I already disabled the configuration, still, archives arent deleted ..

Comment: What is the "show all" rman command?

Comment: shows rman configuration